# Select values from different Dataframe column based on a list of index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is my issue, I have a dataframe, let's say:

```
df = DataFrame({'A' : [5,6,3,4], 'B' : [1,2,3, 5]})
```

I also have a list of index:

```
idx = [1, 2]
```

I would like to store in a list, the corresponding value in each column.
Meaning I want the first value of the col1 and the second value of the col2.

I'm sure there is a simple answer to my issue however I'm mixing everything up with iloc and cannot find a way of developing a optimized method in my case (I have 1000 rows and 4 columns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can try:

you can extract the complete rows and then pick the diagonal elements

```
result = np.diag(df.values[idx])
```

##### Alternative:

1. convert the `dataframe` to `numpy` array.
2. use `numpy indexing` to access the required values.

```
result = df.values[idx, range(len(df.columns))]
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
array([6, 3])
```

Comment: In fact, converting the dataframe to a numpy array solves the issue I expressed in the comment of @AnuragDabas.

Comment: So, If I'm not wrong you need this - `np.diag(df.values[idx])` ??

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
list(df.values[idx, range(len(idx))])
```

Output:

```
[6, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different way:

```
df.stack().loc[list(zip(idx,df.columns[:(len(idx))]))].to_numpy()
```